# jQuery Animate ScrollTop doesnt work on Zurb Foundation

Tags: jquery, css, zurb-foundation

I'm working on a page which needs to scroll on the click of 2 buttons (Features and Sign-up in the header), but I can't get it to work. I've been going at it for an hour now, but simply can't get it to work. Even something simple like running `$("html,body").animate({scrollTop: 500}, 'slow')` in the console doesn't work... Anyone have a clue what this could be?

http://dizzydata.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding a script to load jQuery worked for me:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
```

For the script, I've run:

```
$('html, body').animate({
scrollTop: $('#targetID').offset().top
}, 1000);
```

or this, for 'no scrolling animation' effect:

```
var container = $('html, body'),
scrollTo = $('#targetID');

container.scrollTop(
scrollTo.offset().top - container.offset().top
);
```